# Increase the maximum number of Recently viewed items on stencil theme

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way to increase the maximum number of recently viewed items in stencil theme? Currently the maximum is 5 items showing and I want it to be more like 16 items maximum. I checked the context, it's shows the array of recently viewed items and it just removes the old one and insert the new one.

Answer (score 2):

The recently_viewed_products object will always display 5, and there isn't really a filter that can be applied to the front matter to pull in more than that. The limit is set in the core application. If you wanted to show more products, you'd need to build the logic into your own frontend application. For example, when a new product appears in recently_viewed_products, you might add it to your own array and manage the Recently Displayed products from that custom system. But there isn't really a way to modify the object itself to return more than 5 products.

Comment: Thanks, actually I was looking for "Recently Viewed products", will this work for that?

Comment: Hey sorry--totally misread your question. The front matter attribute for recently viewed doesn't have the same filtering options. It's a boolean, and true is going to give you the default five products. That's baked into the core application, so there's not really a way to modify the number of products that return as a theme developer.